# Matplotlib and a very large number of plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently trying to write a program that serves as an approximation method. The main idea is to 'dig holes' in a larger geometric object, such as a filled circle, which can be done as follows with Matplotlib:

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

phi = linspace(0, 2*pi, 200)
plt.fill(cos(phi), sin(phi), 'black')

precision = 20
for j in xrange(20):
    for i in xrange(precision):
        plt.fill((cos(phi)+j*cos(i*2*pi/precision))/precision, (sin(phi)+j*sin(i*2*pi/precision))/precision, 'white')
plt.show()
```

This produces a nice little image, with in total `1 + 20*precision = 401` 'subplots', i.e. the circles. For my application, I actually need a few billions or more of these, which understandably produces an error (not enough memory, since Matplotlib still keeps all plots after being drawn, and I cannot clear them if I want to keep the final result). Therefore, I tried saving the plot as an image and reloading it during the iteration:

```
for j in xrange(20):
    for i in xrange(precision):
       plt.fill((cos(phi)+j*cos(i*2*pi/precision))/precision, (sin(phi)+j*sin(i*2*pi/precision))/precision, 'white')
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.savefig("temp.png", bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches=0)
    plt.close("all")
    im = plt.imread("temp.png")
    plt.imshow(im, extent = [-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0])
```

This almost works: The image is correctly saved, but there always seems to be a slight padding on the left and bottom, which ruins the whole process, as in each step the image is shifted to the right.

I tried every possible method I could find to remove this padding, but I couldn't find a solution yet. I tried to create axes manually (as I imagine the padding is due to the space left for the labels etc), but this failed too.

I would be very very happy if someone knew how to remove this padding.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to crop the images. You can do this as described [here](http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0202/). If you know exactly how large the borders are you can cut the borders off like this:

```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import numpy as np
  from PIL import Image
  data = np.arange(3000).reshape((100,30))
  plt.imshow(data)
  plt.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches='tight')

  img = Image.open('test.png')
  width, height = img.size
  img2 = img.crop((35,15,width-8,height-35))
  img2.save('test2.png')
```

Here I found the 35, 15, 8 and 35 using trial and error.

Resulting in this picture with no borders:

[image: No borders]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I will now try to use your solution, but it still results in a rather strange image for slightly more complicated figures such as circles, for which it is rather painful to actually determine where the boarder ends (due to the anti-aliasing; this can partly be solved by setting antialiased = False, while plotting). Still, nice workaround for the moment, thanks!